# Programming series of lights that turn on/off

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 5 on/off lights that I would like to be managed dynamically in angular. As seen below:

[image: lights]

These are placed in parallel to a (working) slider and I want them to share the same scope.

The basic logic is that when the slider is at 3, lights 1,2 & 3 should be *ON* and lights 4 & off should be *OFF*. There are two CSS classes to show this *green-on* and *green-off*.

#### Hardcoded HTML:

```
<span class="light green-off"></span><span>4</span><br />
<span class="light green-off"></span><span>3</span><br />
<span class="light green-off"></span><span>2</span><br />
<span class="light green-off"></span><span>1</span><br />
<span class="light red-off"></span><span>OFF</span>
```

I know in angular to create a directive like so:

```
<div lights ng-model="lightValue"></div>
```

#### Directive

```
angularApp.directive('lights', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            return scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal) {
                if (newVal !== null) {
                    //update
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This will listen to the value of lightValue which will range from 0-4.

But I'm stuck as to where to put the logic as aforementioned that will change the class depending on the value.

**Do I create a template or return the HTML in the link and use $compile?**

**Finally, is there a more efficient way than using ifs to assign the class (psuedo code below)?**

```
if (lightValue == 4) {
    light1 = on;
    light2 = on;
    light3 = on;
    light4 = on;
} else if (lightValue == 3) {
    light1 = on;
    light2 = on;
    light3 = on;
} else if (lightValue == 2) {
    light1 = on;
    light2 = on;
} //etc..
```

## Update:

Thanks, I was able to use ngClass with some conditional statements to the desired effect:

```
<span class="light" ng-class="{'green-on' : notches == 4, 'green-off' : notches < 4 }"></span><span>4</span><br />
<span class="light" ng-class="{'green-on' : notches >= 3, 'green-off' : notches < 3 }"></span><span>3</span><br />
<span class="light" ng-class="{'green-on' : notches >= 2, 'green-off' : notches < 2 }"></span><span>2</span><br />
<span class="light" ng-class="{'green-on' : notches >= 1, 'green-off' : notches < 1 }"></span><span>1</span><br />
<span class="light" ng-class="{'red-on' : notches == 0, 'red-off' : notches > 0 }"></span><span>OFF</span>
```

I guess I could try write this into the directive to make it reusable.

Comment: you might get away with writing just one class (on or off) in the css though. standard is off and with the active class, on. saves you one check :) can i have a half-right answer please? xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will assume your slider currently triggers a zero based integer value depending on the position where it is, changing lightValue. then your lights class should activate based on it.

```
<span ng-class="{'green-off' : lightValue <= 4 }" class="light"></span><span>4</span><br />
<span ng-class="{'green-off' : lightValue <= 3 }" class="light"></span><span>3</span><br />
<span ng-class="{'green-off' : lightValue <= 2 }" class="light"></span><span>2</span><br />
<span ng-class="{'green-off' : lightValue <= 1 }" class="light"></span><span>1</span><br />
<span ng-class="{'green-off' : lightValue <= 0 }" class="light"></span><span>off</span>
```

you could of course make this loop dynamic to generate the spans etc.

Answer (score 1):

> ng-class

changes the class according to scope values

from [ng-class official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, red: error}">Map Syntax   Example</p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="deleted"> deleted (apply "strike" class)<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="important"> important (apply "bold" class)<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="error"> error (apply "red" class)
```

> Finally, is there a more efficient way than using ifs to assign the class (psuedo code below)?

yes, just use ng-class and simple logic in your html templates

Answer (score 1):

All you would need is an ng-class on each element like this...

```
<span class="light green-off" ng-class='{your-class-to-add : lightValue == 4}'>4</span>
```

So if 'lightValue' is a variable in your controller, if that variable = 4, then the 'your-class-to-add' class will be added to that element.